# Нечеткая структура научной работы

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как назвать работу (реферат, курсовую, книгу), в которой страдает структура, форма? Н-р: смешиваются темы, не всегда точно и во всем соответствуя разделам, в которых они изложены, нарушен четкий порядок последования тем.

Беспорядочная работа? Не цельная? Бесформенная, бесструктурная?

Answer (score 1):

По логике изложения можно усмотреть в такой работе **фрагментарность**, а по подбору материала - **эклектичность**.

https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/190709

https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_fwords/286

Answer (score 1):

Смотря в какой мере страдает.

Наш преподаватель мог написать: Работа непоследовательная, сбивчивая с нечёткой «рыхлой» структурой. Или: Сырая работа с нечёткой композицией и структурой.

Или: Работа страдает отсутствием логики и чёткости структуры.

Обычно слабые работы, если их всё же засчитывают, характеризуются уклончиво:

Логичность и последовательность в изложении материала содержание реферата соответствует заявленной в названии тематике; в реферате отмечены нарушения общих требований написания реферата; есть погрешности в техническом оформлении; в целом реферат имеет чёткую композицию и структуру, но в тексте реферата есть логические нарушения в представлении материала; в полном объёме представлен список использованной литературы, но есть ошибки в оформлении; некорректно оформлены или не в полном объёме представлены ссылки на использованную литературу в тексте реферата; есть частые орфографические, пунктуационные, грамматические, лексические, стилистические и иные ошибки в авторском тексте; в целом реферат представляет собой достаточно самостоятельное исследование, представлен анализ найденного материала, присутствуют единичные случаи фактов плагиата ...

Comment: Подскажите, "оформление" имеет отношение к логике изложения и структуре работы?  "Есть ошибки в оформлении" , "страдает техническое оформление" - эти выражение синонимичны понятиям "Эклектичная работа", "Фрагментарное изложение"?

Comment: Нет. Оформление - это титульный лист (шрифт, стиль, последовательность слов в "шапке" : куда, кому, что - название учебного заведения и его отнесённость к министерству или другие пометы), кто выполнил, кто руководитель; оглавление (содержание); структура - 3 части, 3 параграфа и т.д.; сноски внизу страницы; таблицы, диаграммы; правильное оформление списка литературы - библиография. Эклектичная работа - это содержание, когда отдельные фрагменты по смыслу совершенно разнородные, иногда противоречивые, нет связок -логических  переходов от одной  к другой тематике.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы сказал, что работе недостаёт внутренней стройности.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, уместнее будет назвать такую работу *непоследовательная работа*. Определения «беспорядочная» и «бесформенная» могут быть оскорбительными для автора работы.

Вообще всё зависит от степени этой непоследовательности и нелогичности. Можно попробовать подыскать определения в форме *работа с нарушением структурности, последовательности*, *с нарушением связности мысли* и т.п.